# bootstrap form helper date picker default

Tags: php, datepicker, bootstrap-form-helper

I am using Bootstrap form helper and want to update the record with new date in which user already selected date earlier. I cannot find the way to display date in date picker from database . 
Following is the code:

the date from db e.g

$date="1990-10-25"

```
      <div class="bfh-datepicker" id="dob" data-name="dob" data-min="01/01/1960" data-max="today" data-format="d/m/y"  ></div>
```

I have tried to add $date variable as placeholder= ”echo $date; ” also date=” echo $date; ”

cannot reach the solution. Need help support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a `data-format` as `d/m/y`. So, you need to pass the date with the same format:

```
<?php
$date= "1990-10-25";
$date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
?>

<div class="bfh-datepicker" data-date="<?php echo $date; ?>" id="dob" data-name="dob" data-min="01/01/1960" data-max="today" data-format="d/m/y"></div>
```